# How to add a tag to a main branch of a code repository in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, version-control, versioning

I'm fairly new to Git (and GitHub), and all my many years of version control come from using ClearCase, so I'm conscious of the fact that I might expect something of GitHub that does not exist.

I have a large python project which I want to bring under version control in terms of GitHub management and an internal version number of our own (held in a text file inside the project root).

After several branches have merged back to the main/master branch, I would like to add some kind of identifier (like a tag), which contains an incremented software version number as described above, to all files across the repository. I understand that files that don't often change tags will stack up.

I would like to use this tag (with the software version number) to retrieve a specific version of the project files when legacy code needs to be retrieved for a rerun of the project.  I understand that GitHub has labels assigned to issues, but I am struggling to visualise how this would work (again, I'm stuck in a very old ClearCase way of thinking).

**My own answer**
Thank you for the comments. I've had time to reflect and come to the following conclusion.

The software version number is held in a text file which is loaded as needed by the software (to be displayed in the GUI and during analysis output). I would clone the project and make several branches as I take on new features and bug requests. Each time a feature of a bug is completed, it's merged back to the main branch (after testing). After finishing all the work, I would make a final branch off of the main branch and only adjust the text file with the version number. Upon performing commit I add a tag using the version number.

Comment: You want to look at ordinary git tags. They are applied to a commit - not to individual files. So as long as something has changed in the repo since last version, there will not be any overlapping tags

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag

Comment: ClearCase (at least the versions I used, pre-UCM) is file-oriented while Git is commit-oriented. This makes substantial changes to the way you need to think about the VCS. As @fredrik said, you tag a specific *commit:* that commit contains a full snapshot of every file (as does, in fact, every commit; the underlying content of files is shared across and even within commits so that the repository doesn't bloat up).

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR

You don't need to do this file by file, just use git tags.

##### The longer story

I faced your issue when I migrated from CVS to Git. My source files used to include version numbers inside them, automatically updated by CVS during my commit process (if I recall correctly). This way, when I looked at a file, I knew which version I was looking at. I fought Git for a while, trying to keep this going, but what I have learned, and my advice to you: just stop keeping version info inside each source files. It's just not Git's model.

Take the time to get familiar with Git's each-commit-is-a-full-snapshot model, embrace it, and you will soon realize how much simpler what you want to do actually is with Git in the first place.

When you check out a particular commit with Git, via its sha-1 or using a tag, you get the state of every single file in the project as of that commit. You no longer need to track which version each file had at that time: that's exactly what a commit does.

I used to keep track of things like "release 1.0 needs file A 1.0 file B 2.4 file C 1.2". My release process had a step that created that list and embedded it in each release. With Git, that's "release 1.0 needs commit <sha1>", which becomes "release 1.0 needs tag v1.0" if you use tags. I no longer feel the need to embed this information is my release, since my tag's name is self explanatory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've had some time to understand the difference between a distributed version control like Git, and one held on a central server like ClearCare.  I don't think I was very clear in my explanation. The version number is not held in the source code. It's held in one text file and loaded as needed.

Comment: OK, so that means part of my longer story doesn't apply to you, but most of it is still relevant: a single tag or sha1 is enough to replace that text file's list. I just read your edit, and what you describe makes sense to me. I'm flag you found a workflow that works for you.